# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "hablar por los codos"?

Tags: expresiones

[Hablar por los codos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9dpTI7F%7C9dqVgC1) viene definido como

> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Hablar demasiado.

y aparece en el diccionario de la lengua ya en 1729 como "Phrase vulgár con que se pondéra y exagéra, que alguno habla mucho".

¿Cual es el origen de esta expresión?

Comment: Hay un libro interesante del mismo nombre, pero solo tiene definiciones sin origenes desafortunadamente. (Es breve y una Buena fuente de refranes)

Answer (score 9):

No he podido encontrar una respuesta definitiva al asunto. La expresión existe también en portugués (*falar pelos cotovelos*), y a ese respecto encontré lo siguiente:

> Como significa "falar demais", esta expressão tem origem nas pessoas
>   que têm por hábito falar demais. Estas pessoas, por possuírem essa
>   característica, conseguem ver a falta de interesse no seu
>   interlocutor, já que a capacidade de atenção de uma pessoa é limitada,
>   principalmente quando a conversa não é interessante. Então, nesse
>   caso, a pessoa que fala demais, toca no cotovelo da outra pessoa, para
>   chamar a sua atenção. É por esse motivo que se diz que uma pessoa
>   "fala pelos cotovelos". O primeiro registro desta expressão é da
>   autoria do escritor latino Quintus Horatius Flaccus (65-8 a.C.), numa
>   das suas sátiras.

Traduciendo en pocas palabras: se dice de la persona que habla mucho que "habla por los codos" porque no sólo habla mucho sino que además **toca con el codo al interlocutor para llamarle la atención** y obligarlo a que siga escuchando. Supuestamente esta expresión aparece ya en las *Sátiras* de Horacio (siglo I a.C.).

Comment: Interesante. En Argentina se dice "Hablar _hasta_ por los codos", que se presta a otra interpretación.

Comment: @fedes. Soy argentino :) pero no creí necesario complicar la respuesta con ese detalle. El significado literal de la frase es diferente, pero de todas formas nadie puede tomar literalmente una expresión como *hablar por los codos*.

Comment: @pablodf76, perdón, no quise implicar que le faltara eso a la respuesta. (Y el +1 que me había olvidado de darte!)

Answer (score 2):

El significado de la hipérbole es claro y queda recogido con similar formulación en lengua portuguesa (“falar pelos cotavelos”), para indicar esa tendencia a la profusión verbal de la que  hacen gala algunos sujetos de los que a veces también decimos que “no callan ni debajo de agua”.

Queda recogida en el Diccionario de Autoridades de 1739, pero se encontraba ya presente en las Sátiras de Quinto Horacio Flaco en el siglo primero antes de Cristo.  Lo que no queda tan claro es por qué la hipérbole descansa en esa parte de la anatomía y se tiende erróneamente a desentrañar el origen de la expresión intentando relacionar el papel que eventualmente puede desempeñar la articulación en determinados actos comunicativos, al servicio de la función fática o con fines expresivos, cuando en realidad se trata de una cuestión de tamaño y no de funcionalidad.

Desde antiguamente el ser humano ha utilizado lo que tenía más a mano (precisamente la mano y el brazo) para calcular medidas, primero de su alrededor y, posteriormente, distancias, aplicando los múltiplos de las mismas.  Han sobrevivido hasta la fecha los términos “pulgadas”, “palmos” y “brazas” en este sentido, que a lo largo de la historia han sido rudimentarios y casi exclusivos instrumentos de medición.  Aún hoy las pantallas de nuestros televisores u ordenadores se miden de esta manera.  Entre estas medidas se encontraba el “cubital”, adjetivo que la Enciclopedia Treccani explica de esta manera:

> cubital adj. [del lat. cubitalis, der. de cubitus “codo”]. 1. [muy grande, dicho especialmente de caracteres: una inscripción con caracteres cubitales].  Colosal, enorme.

Todavía hoy se utiliza en lengua italiana como sinónimo de mayúsculas “escribir en caracteres cubitales”.  El término “cubitalis” pues, era utilizado inicialmente en latín referido a caracteres de inscripciones o avisos cuya importancia requería mayores dimensiones (las de un “cúbito”, es decir, un codo), de manera que fuesen sobradamente claros y expresivos.

A partir de aquí y para que tal uso derive hasta el significado que habitualmente se le atribuye a la expresión, son necesarios dos mecanismos en la evolución del mismo.
El primero afecta al canal comunicativo, el pasaje de lo escrito a lo oral.  “Cubitalis dixit” o “cubitalis dictum”, referido a una inscripción o mensaje escrito, con el sentido de “abundantemente dijo”, “un dicho claro, ostensible”, pasaría a aplicarse a la expresión oral o formulación de esos mismos enunciados con independencia de la escritura.
El segundo mecanismo es el pasaje del “multum” al “multa”, o del “quantum” al “quanta”, es decir, del “mucho” al “muchas cosas”, identificar el haber dicho “claramente, sobradamente, abundantemente, contundentemente” algo con el haber dicho muchas cosas.  La contundencia relacionada con la abundancia de unidades y no con la unidad en sí.  Algo así como identificar algo “grande como un bosque” con algo “con muchos árboles”.

Para aclarar esta última derivación de “cubitalis”, de “grande” a “muchas cosas” basta aclarar otro equívoco frecuente con otro adjetivo latino terminado en “-alis”: “celestialis”.  Gira aún la explicación de que la sangre azul de los monarcas y príncipes proviene del hecho de que lucían por lo general una piel tan clara -debido al hecho de permanecer en palacio o protegidos del sol en sus pocas salidas públicas-, que resaltaba en ellos el color azulado de las venas.  En realidad la sangre azul proviene del adjetivo “celestialis”, que hacía referencia al origen divino de la monarquía y no a la mayor visibilidad de las celestes venas de los miembros de la realeza.  Realeza y no solo.  Quizá algún nostálgico como yo de la peseta todavía recuerde aquello de “caudillo de España por la gracia de Dios”, que “cubitalis dixit”.

Comment: Interesante, pero cuál es el TL;DR? "Hablar por los codos" significa "hablar mucho" porque el codo es una unidad de medida? Es esto especulación razonada o está basado en alguna referencia? Si hay referencia, podrías aportarlas por favor?

Comment: @Rafael Martinez R. Respuestas como ésta, además de informativas, en forma de ensayos breves, son pequeñas joyas entre las que hacen de este sitio un placer leerlo.